# Where to set getShowAmounts in pager.phtml?

Tags: pager

In `template/page/html/pager.phtml` there is the following line which defines whether to show the item count on the product list toolbar:

`<?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>`

Where is `getShowAmounts()` set in the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the construct of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager` showAmounts is set to true using `$this->setData('show_amounts', true);`.

However since on the category page's pager.phtml is usually called using `getPagerHtml()` from within toolbar.phtml and toolbar.phtml by default has it's own amounts html it doesn't really make sense to display it twice so within the `getPagerHtml` method of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` showAmounts is set to false here

```
$pagerBlock->
...
 ->setShowAmounts(false)
...
```

That said if you do need to set it back to true you can observe `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and do something like below.

```
    <?php class Namespace_Name_Model_Observer
{
    public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        $blockNameInLayout = $block->getNameInLayout();

        switch ($blockNameInLayout) {
            case 'product_list_toolbar_pager' :

                $block->setShowAmounts(true);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

Interesting part:

```
public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        $pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

        if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

            /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
            $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

            $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
                ->setShowPerPage(false)
                ->setShowAmounts(false)
                ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
                ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
                ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
                ->setFrameLength(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame'))
                ->setJump(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip'))
                ->setCollection($this->getCollection());

            return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
        }

        return '';
    }
```

Interesting line:
->setShowAmounts(false)

if you want to change it to true you have to override the block with your own module.

Comment: I haven't checked for alternatives. But in this case, you can use an observer which sets the property to true in `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`